# How to apply a display CSS transition delay to a child div

Tags: css, css-transitions

I wish to apply a css transition delay to a child div, for example:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Inner DIV</div>
</div>

#outer:hover #inner{display:none;transition-delay:1s;}
```

Can this be done? If so, what's the magic?

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo** (to fiddle with)</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/uhpszrLx/)

```css
#inner{width:50px;height:50px;background:green;transition:0s display;}

#outer{width:200px;height:200px;background:orangered;}
#outer{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;}

#outer:hover #inner{display:none;transition-delay:1s;}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Inner DIV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "CSS3 Transitions don't apply to the 'display' property" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Comment: Thanks! I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

As iArcadia points out, display cannot be transitioned - so most people animate the visibility/opacity.

HOWEVER, using visibility/opacity might not be an option, because the div-to-be-hidden still exists. In my case, this prevented clicking on the underlying element.

Solution: setting width/height to zero effectively hides the element - and both of those are transitionable.

```js
$('#outer').click(function(){
 $('#outer').toggleClass('cyan');
});
$('#inner').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 return false;
});
```

```css
#outer{width:200px;height:200px;background:orangered;}
#outer{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;}

#inner{width:50px;height:50px;background:green;transition:width 0s;overflow:hidden;}

#outer:hover #inner{width:0px;transition:width 0s linear 3s;}

.cyan{background:cyan !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>DEMO: Click on the red outer box to toggle BG color. Clicking on inner div won't toggle the color UNTIL the inner div is hidden (after 3s).</p>

<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Inner DIV</div>
</div>
```